# Test dispatch action using react testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Hi I have a function as shown below:

```
MyComponent.js-------
const somefunction = () => {
        if (someCondition) {
            dispatch(someActionMethod({
                                   id: 01,
                                   empName: 'Adam'
                                  }).then((result) => {
                                      setSomeState(result.data);
                                 })
                     )
            }
     }
```

Tried a lot of ways to mock someActionMethod with dispatch, but all efforts are failing.

My test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as redux from 'react-redux';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

const useDispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, 'useDispatch');
const mockDispatchFn = jest.fn();

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  const props = {};
  mockDispatchFn.mockReturnValue(
    [{data1},{data2}]
  );
  let componentRendering;
  beforeEach(() => {
      componentRendering = render(
          <MyComponent props={ props } />
  )});

  it('test component', ()=> {
  expect(componentRendering.container.innerHTML).not.toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Throws me error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption from the error message is that your code is expecting a promise somewhere.

The stack trace will have info about the component throwing this error at a specific line.

I would recommend you to check your code and mock all the required methods

I hope this helps in resolving the error

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to mock `useDispatch` instead mocking `someActionMethod`?

```
import * as redux from 'react-redux';

const useDispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useDispatch');
const mockDispatchFn = jest.fn();

// One of these should work
mockDispatchFn.mockReturnValue([{data1}, {data2}]);
useDispatchSpy.mockReturnValue(mockDispatchFn);
```

With your updated response I'd try this:

```
describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  it('test component', () => {
    const props = {};

    const useDispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, 'useDispatch');
    const mockDispatchFn = jest.fn();
    mockDispatchFn.mockReturnValue(
      [{ data1 }, { data2 }],
    );

    render(<MyComponent {...props} />);

    // your assertions here
  });
});
```

Comment: tried with this: mockDispatchFn.mockReturnValue([{data1}, {data2}]);
TypeError: dispatch(...).then is not a function
How would my test know, that in place of someActionMethod, it needs to use mock?

Comment: are you mocking _before_ rendering the component?

Comment: yes, have modified above to show full implementation of test file

Comment: how is `someFunction` being called? onClick? ueEffect?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using it with middleware? I am not sure that dispatch returns a promise nor any value without using middleware.

By the way, mocking a react redux hook is not a recommended way and you could actually see it is not even possible as of version 8 of react-redux package.